# Listen for state changes from redux-thunk action creator

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I can't see a clear way to know when a particular action has fired or particular state has updated from the context of a redux-thunk action creator.

I want to do something like this:

1. Dispatch an action
2. Detect a possible recoverable error condition
3. Error condition dispatches a different action signalling recovery process initiating
4. Wait for recovery to complete
5. Proceed with current action or re-dispatch it

Concrete example:

1. User interaction triggers API call action
2. Note that API call failed, needs login
3. Dispatch 'LOGIN_REQUIRED' action, which pops up a `<dialog>` for user.
4. Wait for logged in state to change (or LOGIN_SUCCESS action to occur, whatever).
5. Make same API call again

Comment: How about passing the failed API call (the uri for instance) along with the LOGIN_REQUIRED action. Then you can use it in the login dialog.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for a specific *action* to be dispatched, you'll need middleware.

If you want to, in effect, "subscribe a given bit of state", Redux doesn't provide a built-in way to do that.  There are, however, a number of utilities that implement that kind of logic for you.  See the Redux FAQ at http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#store-setup-subscriptions , and also the [list of store subscription addons](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/store.md#store-change-subscriptions) in my Redux addons catalog.  (The list of [Redux middlewares](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/middleware.md) may also have something useful for the "listen for an action" scenario.)

Answer (score 0):

for visualizing what happens in store you can use:

```
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension';
```

and create your store as: (for instance with thunk middleware)

```
const store = `createStore(rootReducer,composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));`
```

then you can use the extention in browser.
you can have access to your state by `{connect} from 'react-redux'` as props. 
your actions then will change the state via reducers, this will cause your component receive new props so you can have your logic in

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {/*your business logic*/}
```